# How to determine if end of URL matches "/my-phrase"

Tags: php

I need to execute conditional code if the last part of the URL string is /my-phrase

How can I parse the URL for a match after the last "/" character in the URL string?

```
if(end of URL is "/my-phrase")
{ //dosomething;}
else
{//something else;}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
substr($URL, -1 * strlen("/my-phrase")) == "/my-phrase"
```

Comment: I know this worked when I last checked it, but for some reason I can't get it to work now. echo($URL) is not returning a value. Is $URL a variable or do I have to define it?

Comment: $URL is a variable you already have with the url you want to check.

Answer (score 0):

you can explode on "/". then check the last element

```
$url="http://www.somewhere.com/my-phrase";
$s = explode("/",$url);
if (  end($s) == "my-phrase" ){
 print "found";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The other answers posted so far are good, but I personally prefer the simplicity of:

```
if(preg_match("#/my-phrase$#", $url)) {
  //...
}
```